# How to delete chat history in skype for only one contact in Linux

Tags: skype, delete, history

I'm trying to delete chat history for only one contact in Linux. I've tried sqlite:

`http://www.sqlite.org/download.html`

but it removes chat conversation for a while and after restart skype it returns them back. Is there a way to delete chat for a definite person? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it with [sqliteman](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/).

You can install sqliteman from the **Ubuntu Software Centre**.

First, not just close but really **quit** Skype (right click on the Skype icon in the Unity panel and select quit).

**Now make a backup of the Skype sqlite database. With your favorite file manager go to `$HOME/.skype/YOUR-SYKPE-NAME/` and duplicate the `main.db` file.**

Start sqliteman and open the file `$HOME/.skype/YOUR-SYKPE-NAME/main.db`
You may need enable displaying of hidden files: Do a right click in the file chooser somewhere in the filelist and check "display hidden files".

When opened, on the right site at the top you see the SQL Editor. Run the following SQL-commands, **one by one** by clicking the single green arrow at the top. After **each** run clear the SQL-Editor and paste/edit the next one.

Replace `SKYPE_NAME` with the real Skype name of the Skype partner, not with an alias name!

```sql
DELETE FROM messages WHERE
 dialog_partner="SKYPE_NAME" OR
 chatname LIKE "%/$SKYPE_NAME;%" OR
 chatname LIKE "#SKYPE_NAME/$%"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM chats WHERE
 dialog_partner="SKYPE_NAME" OR
 name LIKE "%/$SKYPE_NAME;%" OR
 name LIKE "#SKYPE_NAME/$%"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM chatmembers WHERE
 identity = "SKYPE_NAME" OR
 chatname LIKE "%/$SKYPE_NAME;%" OR
 chatname LIKE "#SKYPE_NAME/$%"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM participants WHERE identity="SKYPE_NAME"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM conversations WHERE
 identity LIKE "%$SKYPE_NAME;%" OR
 identity = "SKYPE_NAME" OR
 identity LIKE "#SKYPE_NAME/$%"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM transfers WHERE partner_handle = "SKYPE_NAME"
```

```sql
DELETE FROM voicemails WHERE partner_handle = "SKYPE_NAME"
```

Close sqliteman (if asked, you don't need to save changes of the SQL editor) and start Skype. The history of `SKYPE_NAME` should be gone.

Comment: Does it have to be one by one? Can't you just add `;` after each command?

Comment: No, sqliteman dont like `;` - maybe I just dont know how - but if I combine two or more commands in the SQL editor with `;` and linebreaks only the last got executed. I was surprised, too.

Comment: The screenshot on the [sqliteman  home page](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/) seems to indicate it doesn't mind `;`.

Comment: I got it - if there is more than one statement you have to click the double-green-error - shame on me - hmmm, but if I do so, no error but the commands aren't really done, too - crazy

Comment: It seems you need an active cursor in the right context before starting multible commands. I don't know how to achive it and I dont will explore that. It's not intuitive...

Comment: How to install it? I unzip it and entered `cmake .` and after that I tried with: `make install` but it gave me: `No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
`

Comment: What do you try to install? Dont download sqliteman from sourceforge - just install it with the Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: Yes I installed it, but chat conversation is still there. I only replaced  skype name of the person and history is there.

Comment: Are you sure you used the real skype-name and not an alias? Have a look in the profile of that person. There may be a skype-name, a fullname and furthermore a name  you assigned to that person

Comment: Yes, I used real skype name and these queries from answer and logged again and history is there

Comment: I tested it two times here and all history was gone. Did you copy+paste each entire grey block as **one** SQL-statement in the SQL-editor and click the green arrow? Watch the output window below the editor window - are there some errors reported?

Comment: It did not work for me either and I tried also to 'DELETE FROM messages WHERE author="ident"' or to remove whole main.db. Messages somehow reload from server or what.